# Creating new mail (default client) from Java/Windows

Tags: java, windows, explorer, mailto

I want to open the "new mail" view using the default mail client (i.e. open a new mail form in Outlook). But when I go

```
String cmd = "explorer.exe \"mailto:a@b.com?subject="+
             subject+"&body="+body+"\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

the mail shows up, but I have a problem: `explorer.exe` brings up an Internet Explorer instance with a dummy page. Is there a better application to run, such as rundll.exe with certain arguments?

I know it is possible to do it without bringing up iexplore from C++, but I don't know how in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [java.awt.Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail()) (java 6)

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.mail();
```

will open the default mail client (the one associated with mailto: protocol).

Comment: As you see, I want subject and body as well. I would have loved an attachment, but from what I've read, it's not doable.

Comment: The API supports that.

uriMailTo = new URI("mailto", "jonas.bystrom@mentice.com?subject="+
             subject+"&body="+body+"\", null);
dt.mail(uriMailTo);

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I've read some on getting attachments in, but found no real substance. JDIC (which we just finally got rid of) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81862/how-do-i-send-an-email-attachment-using-the-designated-client-programmatically-f are the best I've seen, and none of them are good enough. You wouldn't happen to know more?

Comment: AFAIK that's a limitation of the mailto: protocol, you can't specify an attachment.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer when googling for rundll.exe:

```
String subject = ...;
String body = ...;
String cmd = "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,ShellExec_RunDLL \"mailto:a@b.com?"+
             "subject="+subject+"&body="+body+"\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Jonas: Have you tried ShellExecute() instead of relying on undocumented implementation details that are likely to change in future versions of Windows?

Comment: Larry: I didn't think there was one for Java? As to JNI-ing it, I very much prefer two lines of Java code that might (probably not though) require minor adjustments to 50 lines of code spread over Java, C and build system.